# How should a error monad be defined

Tags: haskell

```
data Error a = OK a | Error String
instance Monad Error where
  return = OK
```

How should i define bind in this case?
`>>= : Error a -> (a->error b) -> error b` this is the type of the function bind for this case i hope it's correct.

```
 OK a >>= f       =               (don't know where to begin need some help) 
 Error err >>=f   =               (in this case can i just return error like = Error err)
```

I also want to know if someone can explain why these usage of seq are problematic.
You can find them on slide(page) 10 
Usage of seq 
http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Education/EDAN40/lectures/Parallelism.pdf
hittendInside xy=someFunc(x 'seq' y) why is this problematic forexamble is it because seq won't return x it will only evaluate it and will only return y.
Is this the case in the other two exambles also?

Comment: You'll need to always capitalise your type as `Error b`, not `error b`. Why not ask your `seq` question as a separate question?

Answer (score 9):

Think of how you would want a pipeline of functions to work

```
---->f---->g---->h---->
     |     |     |
     V     V     V
    Err   Err   Err
```

If no error occurs, the data should just be a straight shot through

```
OK x---->remove OK---->f---->remove OK---->g---->remove OK---->h---->
```

This can be realized by

```
OK x >>= f = f x
```

If at any point you hit an error, the calculation should stop

```
OK x---->remove OK---->f---->Error (Stop!)
```

This can be realized by

```
Error message >>= f = Error message
```

Incidentally, you don't have to write this, it already exists under the name "Either"

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

The monad was set up so that "Right" passes data through (get it- "Right" means "correct"), and Left stops the data (ie- it is "Error").  If you don't want a message, use "Maybe".

Note that this works a lot like exceptions in Java.

Answer (score 1):

For your `OK` case, you have an `a` and a function `(a -> Error b)` and need to return a value of type `Error b`. You can simply apply your function `f` to the value `a` of your `OK`:

```
OK a >>= f = f a
Error err >>= f = Error err
```

Comment: Do u know what map (:) does?